# Bulk change the order status based on a date in Woocommerce

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

The following sql query will change order status:

`update wp_posts set post_status = 'wc-completed' where post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status ='wc-processing' ;`

How can I change the order status only on orders that are before a certain date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bulk change the order status before a date *(for example before the `05 OCT 2018`)* using this SQL query *(making always a database backup before)*:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_status` = 'wc-completed' 
WHERE `post_type` = 'shop_order' 
AND `post_status` ='wc-processing' 
AND `post_date` < '2018-10-05 00:00:00';
```

Tested and works

Comment: Woohoo!  24739 rows affected. (Query took 0.6414 seconds.) Outstanding, thank you.